# Content mix under CC BY 2.0 and CC BY-SA 3.0. Which type of final license should I use?

Tags: cc-by-sa, cc-by

I have a plan to use on my page content mix under different license sources: text materials from Wikipedia under CC BY-SA 3.0, and some images from Flickr under CC BY 2.0  and most part of images from pixabay under original license, which is based on Creative Commons' public domain deed CC0. All links to source pages will be given. Can I finally publish all content under CC BY-SA 3.0 without additional actions or maybe I should use different type of license like CC BY-SA 4.0?

Is I correctly understand CC licenses inner compatibility?

> Blockquote
> For example, CC BY is one-way compatible with BY-SA. You may adapt a BY work and apply BY-SA to your contributions, but you may not adapt a BY-SA work and apply BY to your contributions.

https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/ShareAlike_compatibility

quoted text available under https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/

Answer (score 2):

The cited Creative Commons page states that CC-BY-SA 2.0 and later are compatible with CC-BY-SA-4.0, and CC-BY is broadly compatible with CC-BY-SA. CC0 is essentially public domain, so it is also compatible. So you can use CC-BY-SA-4.0 for any modifications if you want.

In any case, as a courtesy to whoever gets the package, you should state details on the licences of the original, unmodified pieces and how to get them. Just for orderliness, consider keeping the pieces in separate directories. Even better would be to keep your changes separate (as many projects using git do, with the projects used just as submodules).

Note IANAL, even less your lawyer.

Comment: Tnank you!

I plan create a list on links of sources with additional notice about license for every source in special part of site about legals. Is it right and does it enought?

And CC-BY-SA 3.0 is not compatible with CC BY-SA 4.0, so i cannot use parts from content licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0 in my final text under CC BY-SA 4.0, inst't it? So I must use for final content CC BY-SA 3.0 isn't it?